# Can jakarta.annotation.Nullable be used for org.springframework.lang.Nullable?

Tags: spring, nullable, jakarta-annotations

Say I have the following class.

```java
@Validated
@Service
class MyService {

    public void doSome(final @org.springframework.lang.Nullable String string) {
    }
}
```

Can I replace the `org.springframework.lang.Nullable` with `jakarta.annotation.Nullable`?

```
@Validated
@Service
class MyService {

    public void doSome(final @jakarta.annotation.Nullable String string) {
    }
}
```

With the method still work as before?

### Update

I already know the Bean-Validation and it's status of Spring integration.

I'm asking those `@Nullable` annotations, say, with a `package-info.java` of the following.

```java
@org.springframework.lang.NonNullApi
package com.mycompany;
```

Does spring integrated with `jakarta.annotation.Nullable` for the purpose of the `org.springframework.lang.Nullable`?

Comment: Those annotations don't do what you think they do. You want the annotations from the `jakarta.validation` package. Not these ones.